# In the posses of an file diff, can I make up a file b? Knowing that a + b = diff?

Tags: bash, diff

How do I make a file b having file a + diff? Knowing that  - diff a b > c. Where my c is the diff of the two.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621358

Comment: Thank you!!! Your advice helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`patch` is your friend here.

```sh
diff a b > diff     # i'm assuming this is the original scenario
rm b                # b is lost
cp a b
patch b diff        # b is back
```

Comment: `patch -i diff b` or `patch b < diff`

Comment: Show! It worked just fine. Thank you too much!